# SQL join issue with Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, join

i have 2 tables where First table have all the values of category but i dont want to show all categories to every customer so there is a column is_hidden the structure is

```
cat_id    cat_name    is_hidden
  1         cat         no
  2         cat1        no
  3         cat2        no
  4         cat3        no
  5         cat4        yes
  6         cat5        yes
```

Now in my SQL query i  am getting all the values where is_hidden column is no
In my other table i am approving some clients to show the category
The table structure is

```
id   cat_id    client_id
1     5          1
```

Now i want to display all the campaign from table where is_hidden is no and now that i have approved the client in table 2 so it should also show the category id from 5

Now how can i join the SQL  to get the desired result.

Here is my code what i have tried.

```
Approvals::where('client_id',$client_id)
            ->rightJoin('tbl_cat', function ($join) {
                $join->on('tbl_cat.cat_id', '=', 'tbl_approval.approval_id');
                $join->where('tbl_cat.is_hidden','=','no');                
            });
```

But i am not getting the category 5 in output.

Comment: don't use joins. https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships

Comment: @PhilippSander can you guide me how can i do achieve it with relationships

Comment: @sunitiyadav i am using the same code

Comment: @sunitiyadav i think the rightjoin wont work because in where status i am not getting the category 5

Comment: what is approval_id?

Comment: @Nikita id mentioned in second table is approval_id forgot to edit that part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this can't be achieve by join. you should use union all like following

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    table1
WHERE 
    is_hidden = 'no'
UNION ALL
    SELECT
        t.*
    FROM
        table2 t2 INNER JOIN table1 t ON t.id = t2.cat_id
    WHERE
        t2.client_id = 1
```

Comment: Can you convert this query to laravel eloquent. i am getting error when i am changing it to laravel query

Answer (score 0):

Your join should be on `cat_id` so that you will get records of `cat_id` 5.
Hope it will help you.

```
Approvals::where('client_id',$client_id)
            ->rightJoin('tbl_cat', function ($join) {
                $join->on('tbl_cat.cat_id', '=', 'tbl_approval.cat_id');
                $join->where('tbl_cat.is_hidden','=','no');                
            });
```